# How do I install Orfeo toolbox and Qgis 1.9?

Tags: qgis, installation, linux, orfeo-toolbox

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Orfeo toolbox and Qgis 2.0 working. 
I followed the qgis wiki instructios, added the ppa, installed qgis 1.9 (it's beautiful, great work!). 
But when i tried to install the otblib from the ubuntugis repositories, it forces an uninstall of Qgis. 
Any ideas ?

My system is linux mint 15.

Comment: Which packages cause the conflict? You should try to install OTB from source I guess.

Comment: From which repository (ppa) do you try to install OTB and Qgis? OTB is available in the ubuntugis-unstable for Ubuntu and it is compatible in my case with qgis 1.8.0 (Lisboa).

Comment: I'm installing from ubuntugis-unstable,and it asks to remove qgis2.0 before proceding